# phonegap Blackberry webworks plugin

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to create a BlackBerry Webworks plugin using Phone gap. I am trying to follow the instructions given in this link:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How%20To%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks

however, the directory structure mentioned in the link and mine vary significantly, also there is no build.xml in the root directory to run the

ant create-plugin command,

Since Phonegap being converted to Cordova Project, has something changed in the process to be followed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the way plugin is added is different:

- Add customplugin.js to your project's www folder and include a reference to it in your html file after cordova.js.

- Add the plugin source to your cordova.jar in your projects ext folder. Open cordova.jar with your favorite archive manager or use the jar to copy the CustomPlugin.java file into org/apache/cordova/plugins directory.
- In your projects plugins.xml file add the following line:

ref:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/ChildBrowser

Comment: Is there a complete project that teaches - how to build a PhoneGap BB plugin and how to use that plugin in a PhoneGap based BB app.

Comment: template plugin from the phonegap 1.4.0 [plugin template](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-blackberry-webworks.git;a=tree;f=template/plugin;h=448da66c3b7c47019d081d7b93e577160c5ad84a;hb=refs/tags/1.4.0)

Comment: You can refer to the Blackberry core plugin: [Accelerometer.java](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-blackberry-webworks.git;a=blob;f=framework/ext/src/org/apache/cordova/accelerometer/Accelerometer.java;h=2088122be3512252354c027c99d20cd5274da80d;hb=HEAD) wiki for creating the blackberry plugin(it is old one) [wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How-To-Create-a-PhoneGap-Plugin-for-BlackBerry-WebWorks)